# Segoe UI Symbols - Programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

**EDIT:**

Below is the format of my XML. It contains data for my IconSheet. I just put only one icon Hex Value for sample.

```
<Item>
  <ItemInfo>
    <Value>uE101</Value>
    <Name>1</Name>
  </ItemInfo>
</Item>
```

Here is a snippet from my Code

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        data = (from query in XElement.Load("Data.xml").Descendants("ItemInfo")
                select new ItemInfo
                {
                    value = (int)(query.Element("Value").Value),
                    name = (string)query.Element("Name")
                }).ToList();
        int itemcount = data.length;
        while (itemcount-- > 0)
        {
            TextBlock t = new TextBlock()
            {
                Width = 75,
                Height = 75,
                Text = @"\" + data[itemcount].value,
                FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Symbol")
            };
            wrapPanel.Children.Add(t);

        }
    }
```

in the Snippet Above data[itemcount].value contains data as "uE101". This does not work.

Below code works.

```
Text = "\uE101"
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

With Help from **har07** and **mishan** comments i now have a clear cut idea as to how to handle HEX codes in C#. Thanks for the help. But i Updated the Question what I am trying with and this is what is causing the problem for me.

Comment: try using Text = @"\" + data[itemcount].value.ToString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't separate backslash from next characters in this case. This code :

```
@"\" + "uE101"
```

is equal to this :

```
"\\uE101"
```

which will output this string instead of special character :

```
\uE101
```

They need to be written as single string expression :

```
"\uE101"
```

**UPDATE :**

You can either go with @mishan's second solution by storing only hexadecimal part of the character in xml (`<Value>E101</Value>`), then parse it to int -> convert int to char -> convert char back to string (following is the example to clarify what I mean) :

```
.....
TextBlock t = new TextBlock()
            {
                Width = 75,
                Height = 75,
                Text = ((char)int.Parse(data[itemcount].value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString(),
                FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Symbol")
            };
.....
```

Or to write the exact character to xml and specify xml encoding to a format that support your special characters. You didn't show the codes to create that xml, so I can't help with exact sample that close to yours. But you can search for this topic by keyword "*c# write xml document with specific encoding*" and will find many examples.

Comment: The problem is with the conversion of character code into character, which obviously would not happen when adding strings together. The options I know about is either add the backslash when creating the data[](so it will actually contain finished character) or getting just the sequence "E101" as 16bit hexadecimal number and converting it to character and then to string. The small u is actually part of an escape character sequence - more on this in here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx

Comment: ( \uE101 = \uxxxx - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxx )

Comment: @mishan read **Encoding** part in that link. `Char` is not enough to represent unicode char, it must be represented as string of 2 characters. I don't think the second option will work, since you can't *convert it to character, then to string*

Comment: Good reference anyway, I didn't aware of fact that unicode special charactes are represented as 2 chars string before. I knew that \u is unicode escape sequence, hence we can't separate backslash from u

Comment: about the storing as hexadecimal number - what about for example `((char)0xE101).ToString()` - that's converting hexadecimal number into character and then to string..... Well the truth being that I'm working on Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML project using .NET 4.5 - where **chars ARE UNICODE**

Comment: Ok, I get what you meant in the 2nd option now.

Comment: I apologize for not putting forth the question completely. I updated my question.

Comment: @har07 This worked. Thanks so much. Marked as an answer.

Comment: glad to hear that, but hmm.. I see the mark is in the other answer though :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, **har07** answered your problem in his reply, so I'll just add some possible solutions that come to mind.

**1.STORE THE WHOLE CHARACTERS**

- add the backslash to the data - then it will work
- *When creating the data, add the backslash to it immediately so it's already complete*

**2. STORE CHARACTERS AS (HEXADECIMAL) NUMBERS**

**or store them as characters right away, that would be the best option**

- when you need to assemble them for some reason, you just do conversion from numbers to characters and voila....

EXAMPLE:

```
while (itemcount-- > 0)
    {
        //can be achieved if data[].value is integer
        //for testing purposes 
        //I used integer with value 0xE101
        //int a = 0xe101;

        TextBlock t = new TextBlock()
        {
            Width = 75,
            Height = 75,
            Text = ((char)data[itemcount].value).ToString(),

            //Text = ((char)a).Tostring(),

            FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Symbol")
        };
        wrapPanel.Children.Add(t);

    }
```

---

### THE UPDATE TO MY ANSWER

1. **the easiest solution to this would be if you could save the whole code in xml.**
   *and by this I mean if you could add the backslash (`\`) before the `uE101`*

   ```
   <Item>
     <ItemInfo>
      <Value>\uE101</Value> //see the added "\" character?
      <Name>1</Name>
     </ItemInfo>
   </Item>
   ```

   And the C# code:

   ```
   data = (from query in XElement.Load("Data.xml").Descendants("ItemInfo")
   select new ItemInfo
   {
       value = query.Element("Value").Value, //provided value is of string type
       name = query.Element("Name").Value
   }).ToList();
   ```
2. **store just the HEX values, without the "u" in front** *like `E101`, not `uE101`, and translate them to ints....*

   ```
   //the conversion from STRING CONTAINING HEXADECIMAL CHARACTERS to INTEGER
   //can be done by standard methods included in basic interger...
   //YOUR'S doesn't work because you didn't remove the `u` in front of the HEX VALUE
   //in string - and i'm  also not sure about the implicit conversion between
   //hexadecimal string and integer....

   //so, the improved version of your code using the stuff you have now
   private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       //this should work for values stored as integer
       data = (from query in XElement.Load("Data.xml").Descendants("ItemInfo")
           select new ItemInfo
           {
               value = int.Parse(query.Element("Value").Value.ToString().Substring(1),NumberStyles.HexNumber),
               name = query.Element("Name").Value
           }).ToList();
       int itemcount = data.length;
       while (itemcount-- > 0)
       {
           TextBlock t = new TextBlock()
           {
               Width = 75,
               Height = 75,
               Text = @"\" + data[itemcount].value,
               FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Symbol")
           };
           wrapPanel.Children.Add(t);

       }
   }
   ```

### CONCLUSION

**IMHO the best solution I can think of top of my head is to store the XML with the backslash in the value and when reading, having the *`ItemInfo`* class contain two strings - value and name**

Comment: Hey @mishan, I updated my Question. Please check now.

Comment: updated my answer accordingly. There might be mistakes - I wrote it without checking and seeing if all this stuff can be done with WP8 (or any code control for that matter)

Comment: unfortunately, solution no.1 won't work because XElement.Load will escape backslashes by default, hence this part `query.Element("Value").Value` will return string \uE101 instead of special char.

Comment: my bad. I'll look into it when I have time.